# separate GET request path from query variables

Tags: node.js, url

I have the url: http://www.localhost:8080/api/numbers/prime?amount=13
via GET request

I want to get **api/numbers/prime**
is there any way to do that in node.js vanilla?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript split and slice methods on Strings.

```
let url = "http://www.localhost:8080/api/numbers/prime?amount=13";
let urlWithoutQuery = url.split("?")[0];
let path = urlWithoutQuery.slice(25); // To get the value after http://www.localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html):

```
const url = new URL('http://www.localhost:8080/api/numbers/prime?amount=13')
```

then:

```
console.log(url.pathname); 
// outputs: 
// /api/numbers/prime

console.log(url.searchParams); 
// outputs:
// URLSearchParams { 'amount' => '13' }

console.log(url.search);
// outputs:
// ?amount=13
```